# What are the correct P(x) and Q(x) for this nonhomogenous first order diferrential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve the following differential equation,:

$$X'+\frac{1}{a}X=Cn(x)$$

Where a and C are real constants. If we considered a generic DE, with the following form:

$$X'+P(x)X=Q(x),~~with~~f(a)=b$$

Then the solution is given by:

$$X=f(x)=be^{-\int_a^xP(t)dt}+e^{-\int_a^xP(t)dt}\int_a^xQ(t)e^{\int_a^xP(t)dt}dt$$

So for my case we have:

- $P(x)=\frac{1}{a}$
- $Q(x)=Cn(x)$
- $a=-\infty$
- $f(a)=f(-\infty)=b=0$

When I try to solve the integral of P(t) it explodes to infinity. Can someone recommend some further reading or some tips?

ps: I don't expect the answer to the problem, I'd prefer some guidance.

Edit: Here's what's it's supposed to give:
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LyPn.png)

Comment: Where's this $a=-\infty$ conclusion coming from? Or are you overloading the symbol $a$ by having it both as a coefficient in the equation and as a boundary point?

Comment: In any case unless $n(x)$ behaves quite unusually, this will go to zero at whichever infinity has the same sign as $a$ in the equation. You usually can't force it to go to zero at the other infinity (though you can in the homogeneous case).

Comment: The infinity comes from a physics problem, I'll link the image in a second.

Comment: There's also a sign error in your solution, the exponentials on the outside of the integrals should have a minus sign.

Comment: Thanks,I fixed it.

Comment: Anyway, so I think I see your problem. You're trying to look at $\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{a} dt$ and it diverges no matter what $x$ is. The point here is that the two integral operations aren't really the same type of operation. The one inside the exponential is just being used to get an integrating factor and so it can be based anywhere, it doesn't have to be based at the point where your IVP is set.

Comment: (Cont.) So here you can conveniently choose it to be based at $0$ instead. The one on the outside technically needs to be based at the point where your IVP is set in order for the formula to look like this.

Comment: Really ? that makes sense! But why use the same letter when the interval is arbitrary for the integrals inside the exponential?

Comment: A few things. First I actually made a mistake, in that the correct coefficient in the homogeneous solution is only just $y_0$ if the integral for the integrating factor is based at $x_0$. In your context that doesn't really matter anyway because that term drops out. Second you also made a mistake: the integral on the inner exponential should be going up to $t$, the variable of the inner integral. Besides that, except when dealing with possible divergences, you can base the integral for the integrating factor wherever you want.

Comment: Remember that the integrating factor is just a function you multiplied on both sides of the equation after you made it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123986/discussion-between-w-h-and-ian).